# manually installing update patches of android studio on win os

Tags: android

I wanted to update my *android studio* from **v 1.2.2 (build 141.1980579)** to **v 1.3.0 (build 141.2117773)** through update mechanism of Android Studio but was facing problems due to network breakdown. So I manually download the jar file (through download manager) and followed the below procedures:

Downloaded jar file: **AI-141.1980579-141.2117773-patch-win.jar**
OS platform: **Windows 7 (build 7601)**
Location of Android Studio: **D:\Android Studio**
Location of downloaded jar file: **D:\Downloads**

I opened up a command window in *D:\Downloads* and entered the following command line:

**java -classpath AI-141.1980579-141.2117773-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install "D:\Android Studio"**

Execution cum update started but after completion, update was not a success. How to manually update the same? Any suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 16):

1. Download update. https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-173.4697961-173.4720617-patch-win.jar
2. Press the SHIFT key and right-click inside the folder, then click on "Open Command Window Here" to open the Command Prompt(CMD) at the current address.
3. java -Xmx1024m -classpath AI-173.4697961-173.4720617-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Ensure to open CMD in elevated mode.

Comment: Note that java executable must be placed in a location other than android studio's installation. Just copying 'Android Studio\jre' folder to a temporary location and changing java path in environment variables worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I have bad internet connection so i had to download the AI-**-patch-win.jar externally.
(to get the Download url, start the update process and let it fail, it will pop up a error with the url)

Steps :

1. AI-**-patch-win.jar
2. start CMD with Admin rights or else it wont work.
3. locate or change you dir to AI-**-patch-win.jar
4. enter :

   java -Xmx1024m -classpath AI-**your-file**-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
5. Java update window will open and let it do its job.
6. DONE

---

if any error :
in my case, after step 4. it gave me error that some files were modified.
to solve this i had to open my old Android Studio setup file (930mb) in 7zip,
and look for those file which were in conflict -> extract those file -> paste them in the
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio...\your conflict file..\,
then again follow all this steps. :)

---

**UPDATE**

to get download link :

1. https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-$FROM-$TO-patch-$OS.jar
2. change '$FROM' to your current build (eg. 182.5107.16.33.5264788)
3. change '$TO' to your update build (eg. 183.5429.30.34.5452501)
4. change '$OS' to your platform (eg. unix OR win OR mac)

link for update versions :

https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml

Answer (score 3):

Okay, i used to have the same problem as you but this helped me fix it. Just immediately after the '-classpath', you have to specify the location of the patch file. Forinstance, C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\AI-141.1980579-141.2117773-patch-win.jar and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command line:
java -classpath AI-173.4907809-181.5540.7.32.5056338-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"

for update Android stuio to version 3.2